# HTTP request header attributes path, domain vs SameSite

Tags: http, security, csrf-protection

If in http response header the "set-cookie" properties "path" and "domain" are set for a site say a.com as path=/, domain=a.com

The role of path and domain states-
path: url path that must exist in request resource
domain: restrict host to which cookies will be sent

not what is the role of setting "SameSite" property? as it's use case states cookie not to be sent along with cross-site requests. as the cookie scope is already restraint to same domain by path and domain attributes.

will SameSite: Lax ovewrites the restriction imposed by path/domain

Comment: What do you mean by "SameSite property"?

Comment: sameSite is a property for set-cookie in response header

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#SameSite_cookies

Comment: Ah, please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

*What is the role of setting "SameSite" property?*

There are 2 concept here: the requested resource and where that request is originated. For example, you are visiting a.com, and sends an HTTP request to b.com (through Ajax or image loading or hyperlink etc.) In this scenario, the requested resource is data in b.com, while the request is originated from a.com

**`domain` and `path` is used to restrict which requested resource the cookie can be applied, while `SameSite` is used to restrict where that request should be originated.**

For example, if `domain` is `c.com`, it won't be applied in request sent to b.com, no matter whether that request is sent from b.com website or not. Meanwhile, if `SameSite` is `Strict`, as long as you are not in b.com website, the HTTP request to b.com won't bring that cookie, even if that "SameSite-Strict" cookie's `domain` is `b.com` and `path` is `/`.

*Will SameSite: Lax ovewrites the restriction imposed by path/domain?*

No. `SameSite` and `domain/path` are 2 different thing.